# Как разобрать выражение js

Tags: javascript

Как работает эта странная конструкция на js ?

```
10 > 1 ? 15 < 2 ? 7 > 3 ? 'variant 1' : 'variant 2' : 'variant 3' : 'variant 4'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это [тернарный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), более лёгкая форма обычного `if{}else{}`, однако возвращает истинное значение:

```
a = 2 > 5 ? 'o_O' : true; // a === true
```

---

В Вашем случае, операторы просто вложены (не рекомендуется так делать, тяжело для чтения).
Можно переписать так:

```js
if (10 > 1) { // true, we need to go deeper
  if (15 < 2) { // false, go to else statement
    if (7 > 3) {
      console.info('variant 1');
    } else {
      console.info('variant 2');
    }
  } else { // Execute!
    console.info('variant 3');
  }
} else {
  console.info('variant 4');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю из грамматики JavaScript, то каждое подвыражение за исключением начального условия условного оператора в свою очередь может включать условный оператор

Поэтому данное выражение

```
10 > 1 ? 15 < 2 ? 7 > 3 ? 'variant 1' : 'variant 2' : 'variant 3' : 'variant 4'
```

можно представить как цепочку вложенных условных операторов

```
10 > 1 ? ( 15 < 2 ? ( 7 > 3 ? 'variant 1' : 'variant 2' ) : 'variant 3' ) : 'variant 4'
```

В результате значением выражения будет строка `'variant 3'`

Answer (score 2):

Сначала отформатировать по-человечески

```
10 > 1 
  ? 15 < 2
    ? 7 > 3
      ? 'variant 1'
      : 'variant 2'
    : 'variant 3'
  : 'variant 4'
```

а потом читать так же, как вложенные if-else:

```
if (10 > 1)
  if (15 < 2)
    if (7 > 3)
      return 'variant 1'
    return 'variant 2'
  return 'variant 3'
return 'variant 4'
```